# Mongoose — How do I change a query for a given collection dynamically?

Tags: mongoose

for what I could read in the docs and examples, I can only select a given collection when registering a model, like

```
const Logs = mongoose.model('Logs', LogsSchema, 'myCollection');
```

but when I have a different collections per environment, for example:

```
Logs-Production
Logs-Stage
Logs-Dev
```

How can I query the correct collection in the same application instance?

I've tried doing the registration when I call `Find` to only get

> "Cannot overwrite `Logs` model once compiled."

```
const find = options => {
   const Logs = mongoose.model('Logs', LogsSchema, 'Logs-' + options.env);
   Logs.find({name: options.name}, (err, docs) => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(docs, null, 4);
   });
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to have a prior check if that collection was already registered in the given collection ...

Is there a way to execute the `find()` query on the correct collection without any registration errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Discriminator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) feature of Mongoose? Using this, you can create a Base Log object and extend Prod/Dev/UT from the Base object. Mongoose will internally segregate between the types and choose the exact one for your queries...

[Simple example here](https://dev.to/helenasometimes/getting-started-with-mongoose-discriminators-in-expressjs--22m9)...

Cheers!

SG

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, as I said [on GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8205#issuecomment-537042655) the idea is to be able to change the collection on runtime, not when you're registering the schema... I can't change the code everytime I have a new environment (new branch name) for example...